# QueryDslPredicateExecutor working with spring boot version 1.4.2.RELEASE but not working with spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, querydsl

When I try to migrate my Spring Boot application from version 1.4.2.RELEASE to version 2.2.6.RELEASE I found that org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor not found

Cannot resolve symbol QueryDslPredicateExecutor

i should add spring-data-commons version 1.12.8.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>1.12.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and then i found another probleme
[image]
GitHub repo: https://github.com/dali05/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules

thnaks

Answer (score 7):

Please note that the name of the class over time has been changed, in that one 'D' has changed from its uppercase to a lowercase 'd', ie: `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` is now `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`. Probably this caused some headache for you as it did for me too.

Refer to the class in your source code as Query**dsl**PredicateExecutor and your source code will build again.

Comment: Thanks @SaWo, that was very useful! I inherited some code and didn't think to check for renames.